# Расчет рейтинга постов за все время с момента создания

Tags: математика, логика, формулы

Интересуют результирующие формулы, задачка такая (пример):

**у нас есть 5 постов:**

А: первый пост 1 янв. 2015, последний 1 дек. 2015 и всего 300 раз был репост

Б: первый пост 1 янв 2015, последний 1 янв. 2016 и всего 100 раз был репост

В: первый 1 янв. 2016, последний 1 апр. 2016 и было 30 репостов

Г: первый 1 янв. 2014, последний 1 апр. 2016 и было 3 репоста

Д: единственный пост 1 апр. 2016

Формула **[количество репостов] / ([текущая дата] - [дата 1ого поста])** - ***не подходит*** по понятным причинам, она не отражает реальную текущую релевантность поста. Надо как-то включить дату последнего поста, возможно еще какие-то данные, в целом, можно добавить, *что известны даты каждого из репостов*. То есть построить график репостов - возможно.